# I keep receive error on paypal php adaptive payment API payment "Your payment can't be completed..."

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I try sample files inside latest php API for adaptive payment (1.96) and creating a primary pay. then did pay with my sandbox account and every things working fine.

I use the same process and integrate API with my php application.

I'm able to create primary payment and get payKey. I use payKey and do payment. I login with my sandbox personal account and click pay then see this problem:

Your payment can't be completed. Please return to the participating website and try again.

**Note**: I did not change any config.ini information.

I create multiple pre-confiq accounts in my developer and put them as sender or receiver through sample and application test.

both API sample and application  environment are virtual hosted on my local machine.

[this is paymentDetail object info](http://pastebin.com/dY40Qhqm)

Comment: Anyone else experiencing this problem, see my answer on [Chained payment cannot be completed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26984099/3917091). I'm hesitant to flag any of these questions as duplicates because people find different reasons for the cause of this very vague answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problem.
I was resetting test account and creating new test emails that noted on one suggested solution and forgot to replace new email in my integrated application.

by the way replacing new email solved my problem.